# Filter column by group based on another column (R dplyr)

Tags: r

I want to group a column and filter based on occurrence of certain values in another column. In my case, I have an ID variable and want to keep only instances where Time = 1 and = 2. This is a larger dataset so I'm not able to simply keep duplicates.

I tried using `group_by` and `filter`, but it has not produced the desired table.

```
df <- tibble(s1 = c(1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1004), s2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1))
df_filter <- df %>% 
  group_by(s1) %>% 
  filter(all(c(1, 2)) %in% s2)
```

**Input:**

| ID | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 |
| 1001 | 2 |
| 1002 | 1 |
| 1002 | 2 |
| 1003 | 2 |
| 1004 | 1 |

**Desired Output:**

| s1 | s2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 |
| 1001 | 2 |
| 1002 | 1 |
| 1002 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `n()` from `dplyr` library. It will give you the count of rows. Then you can compare it with 1.

Here's how you can do it:

```
df_filter <- df %>% 
  group_by(s1) %>%
  filter(n() > 1)
```

And if you want only `1` or `2` in `s2`, then you can extend your filter like this:

```
df_filter <- df %>% 
  group_by(s1) %>%
  filter(s2 == 1 | s2 == 2) %>%
  filter(n() > 1)
```